# Finish if-else conditional block in JADE

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, template-engine

I want to finish a `if else` conditional block in [Jade](http://jade-lang.com), so after if/else nested code can be added.

```
- var name = 'you';
- if(name != '')
    p Hello #{name}
- else
    p Hello world
| !!!
```

With an empty name var I want to get

```
<p>Hello you!!!</p>
```

But I get

```
<p>Hello world</p>
!!!
```

With `name = you` I want to get

```
<p>Hello world!!!</p>
```

What I have to change to put more text/tags inside p elements? I mean nested to if/else block and common for both cases. The point is not to repeat in code `!!!`

A finally block like with try/catch would be good, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Just use: p Hello world!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curly braces work inside the inline code

```
- var name = 'you';
- if(name != '') {
    p Hello #{name}
- } else {
    p Hello world
- }
| !!!
```

[image]

---

> how you do to put a tag inside both p? eg strong !!!. With your solution, exclamations are brothers of p elements, no of children, no matters if I tabulate strong tag

Simply move the `p` tag outside of the if-else block and use `|` there instead.

```
div
    - var name = 'you';
    p
        - if(name != '') {
            | Hello #{name}
        - } else {
            | Hello world
        - }
            strong !!!
```

Comment: This is closer of want I was looking for. Now how you do to put a tag inside both p? eg strong !!!. With your solution, exclamations are brothers of p elements, no of children, no matters if I tabulate strong tag

Comment: Simply move the `p` tag outside of the if-else block and use `|` there instead. Checkout the edit

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the `!!!` part to the original text content:

```
if(name != '')
   p Hello #{name}
else
   p Hello world!!!
```

`| !!!` is outside of the `else` block and adds a textNode to the parent tag.

For adding a tag to the `p` tag you can nest it:

```
if(name != '')
   p Hello #{name}
else
   p 
      b Hello world
      | !!!
```

Edit: For not repeating yourself you could also code:

```
- name = name || 'world';
p 
  | Hello #{name}
  | !!!
  b ...
```

Or:

```
p 
  = "Hello " + ( name || "world" )
  | !!!
```

Comment: Of course I can add text inside. !!! is just an example, I want to add more common code (plenty of tags) for both cases (if and else), not just to one case. The point is find a way to not repeat code

Comment: @Mikel I updated the answer with an example snippet that follows DRY principle.